# Rendering SSRS Report to landscape-format PDF in C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rendering, landscape, export-to-pdf

I'm rendering an SSRS report to PDF in my C# code successfully.  However, I need it the PDF to be in landscape format and I've been unable to get that to work.

I've tried setting the pagewidth and PageHeight accordingly in the DeviceInfo, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.  I've also mucked with pageSettings to no avail.

```
    Uri oUri = new Uri(GlobalClass.gReportServerURL);

    //Run report
    rpt.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/" + sReportName;

    rpt.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = oUri;
    paramList.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter ("ClientID", sClientID));

    rpt.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);

    deviceInfo = $@"<DeviceInfo>
                                <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>
                                <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>
                                <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>
                                <MarginTop>.25in</MarginTop>
                                <MarginLeft>.25in</MarginLeft>
                                <MarginRight>.25in</MarginRight>
                                <MarginBottom>.25in</MarginBottom>
                            </DeviceInfo>";

    ms = (MemoryStream)rpt.ServerReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, null, out  mimeType, out fileNameExtension);

    //Write it to disk
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
    fs = new System.IO.FileStream(sFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    fs.Close();
    addPDFToList(sFile);
    lstKillFiles.Add(sFile);
    return sFile;
```

I expect the PDF file to be in landscape orientation, but it is not.

Comment: Could you try making setting changes on Report in visual studio (I mean on report directly, rather than setting through c#). Try to export report as PDF on SSRS and  with C# as well. If this works then you can replicate those properties in your c# code.

Comment: Ok. Stupid question time... Does the SSRS report itself have the page setting to landscape?